# What value should I pass to paperclip to make it so that the file does not update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

When I update a file in my app, it deletes and then re-saves the paperclip file.  I wan't to pass something in to the update_attributes that allows for paperclip to just ignore it, but not delete the current file.  What would I pass in?

I currently just passing in the file, which deletes and resaves.

Comment: During update maybe do not pass any data during update.

Answer (score 0):

you might be using something like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :attachment,
  :url => :attachment_url,
  :path => :attachment_path,
  :default_url => "/images/sheet.png"

end
```

Try adding `:preserve_files => false`. This way when you add a new file previous file are reserved and not deleted.

Final result would be something like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :attachment,
  :preserve_files => false,
  :url => :attachment_url,
  :path => :attachment_path,
  :default_url => "/images/sheet.png"

end
```

Check http://www.codesapling.com/blog/2014/01/10/saving-all-uploaded-attachments-with-paperclip/

Answer (score 0):

I would start by not sending the attachment attribute through [`strong_params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters):

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def update
      @model = Model.find id
      @model.update(update_attributes)
   end

   private

   def update_attributes
      params.require(:model).permit(:attributes, :excluding, :attachment)
   end
end
```